# Xorg seemingly ignores keyboard settings

Tags: linux, keyboard, arch-linux, xorg

This is really a duplicate of [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/1406121/xorg-keyboard-settings-in-xorg-conf-d-dont-work) but that one is over a month old and no one has answered it so I'm asking again. In `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-keyboard.conf` (it was generated by localectl but that shouldn't really make any difference right?) I have the settings

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "system-keyboard"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
    Option "XkbLayout" "is,gb"
    Option "XkbOptions" "grp:alt_shift_toggle,caps:swapescape"
EndSection
```

Running `setxkbmap -print -verbose 10` returns

```
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     is,gb
options:    terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+is+gb:2+inet(evdev)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
xkb_keymap {
    xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)" };
    xkb_types     { include "complete"  };
    xkb_compat    { include "complete"  };
    xkb_symbols   { include "pc+is+gb:2+inet(evdev)+terminate(ctrl_alt_bksp)"   };
    xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc105)" };
};
```

Indicating, strangely enough, that the layouts were applied but not the options. There is even an option in a different file that was applied, but not the ones in `00-keyboard.conf`. The output from `localectl status` seemingly implies that the options were applied when they were not

```
System Locale: LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
   VC Keymap: is-latin1
  X11 Layout: is,gb
 X11 Options: grp:alt_shift_toggle,caps:swapescape
```

If I run `setxkbmap -option grp:alt_shift_toggle,caps:swapescape` everything works as intended, so that functionality itself isn't broken. I'm using i3wm and LightDM on Antergos, so there's almost certainly nothing that's overriding the settings. The Xorg log is as follows.

```
   [   464.883] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Tue Mar 19 17:14:57 2019
[   464.883] (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   464.883] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   464.883] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   464.883] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   464.883] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   464.883] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   464.883] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using the first device section listed.
[   464.883] (**) |   |-->Device "Intel Graphics"
[   464.883] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[   464.883] (**) Option "DontZap" "false"
[   464.883] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   464.883] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   464.883] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   464.883] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[   464.883] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   464.883] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/Type1" does not exist.
[   464.883]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   464.883] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi".
[   464.883]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   464.883]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi").
[   464.883] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi".
[   464.883]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   464.883]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi").
[   464.883] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/TTF,
    /usr/share/fonts/OTF
[   464.883] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   464.883] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   464.883] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   464.883]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   464.883]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.0
[   464.883]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[   464.883]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[   464.884] (++) using VT number 7

[   464.884] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[   464.885] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   464.895] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 8086:191e:1043:1cfd rev 7, Mem @ 0xde000000/16777216, 0xc0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   464.895] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[   464.895] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   464.896] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   464.898] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   464.898]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.0
[   464.898]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[   464.898] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[   464.898] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[   464.898] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   464.898]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 2.99.917
[   464.898]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   464.898]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[   464.898] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[   464.898] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics
[   464.898] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics
[   464.898] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics
[   464.898] (II) intel(0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20181204
[   464.898] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled from 2.99.917-863-g6afed33b
[   464.919] (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) HD Graphics 515
[   464.919] (--) intel(0): CPU: x86-64, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, avx, avx2; using a maximum of 2 threads
[   464.919] (II) intel(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[   464.919] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[   464.919] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[   464.919] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   464.919] (**) intel(0): Option "SwapbuffersWait" "true"
[   464.919] (**) intel(0): Option "TearFree" "true"
[   464.919] (II) intel(0): Output eDP1 has no monitor section
[   464.919] (**) intel(0): Found backlight control interface intel_backlight (type 'raw') for output eDP1
[   464.919] (II) intel(0): Enabled output eDP1
[   464.919] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI1 has no monitor section
[   464.920] (II) intel(0): Enabled output HDMI1
[   464.920] (--) intel(0): Using a maximum size of 256x256 for hardware cursors
[   464.920] (II) intel(0): Output VIRTUAL1 has no monitor section
[   464.920] (II) intel(0): Enabled output VIRTUAL1
[   464.920] (--) intel(0): Output eDP1 using initial mode 1920x1080 on pipe 0
[   464.920] (**) intel(0): TearFree enabled
[   464.920] (==) intel(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[   464.920] (==) intel(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[   464.920] (II) Loading sub module "dri3"
[   464.920] (II) LoadModule: "dri3"
[   464.920] (II) Module "dri3" already built-in
[   464.920] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[   464.920] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[   464.920] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[   464.920] (II) Loading sub module "present"
[   464.920] (II) LoadModule: "present"
[   464.920] (II) Module "present" already built-in
[   464.920] (II) intel(0): SNA initialized with Skylake (gen9) backend
[   464.920] (==) intel(0): Backing store enabled
[   464.920] (==) intel(0): Silken mouse disabled
[   464.920] (II) intel(0): HW Cursor enabled
[   464.920] (==) intel(0): DPMS enabled
[   464.920] (==) intel(0): Display hotplug detection enabled
[   464.921] (II) intel(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[   464.921] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965
[   464.921] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: va_gl
[   464.921] (II) intel(0): direct rendering: DRI2 DRI3 enabled
[   464.921] (II) intel(0): hardware support for Present enabled
[   464.921] (II) Initializing extension Generic Event Extension
[   464.921] (II) Initializing extension SHAPE
[   464.921] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SHM
[   464.921] (II) Initializing extension XInputExtension
[   464.921] (II) Initializing extension XTEST
[   464.921] (II) Initializing extension BIG-REQUESTS
[   464.921] (II) Initializing extension SYNC
[   464.922] (II) Initializing extension XKEYBOARD
[   464.922] (II) Initializing extension XC-MISC
[   464.922] (II) Initializing extension SECURITY
[   464.922] (II) Initializing extension XFIXES
[   464.922] (II) Initializing extension RENDER
[   464.922] (II) Initializing extension RANDR
[   464.923] (II) Initializing extension COMPOSITE
[   464.923] (II) Initializing extension DAMAGE
[   464.923] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[   464.923] (II) Initializing extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[   464.923] (II) Initializing extension RECORD
[   464.923] (II) Initializing extension DPMS
[   464.923] (II) Initializing extension Present
[   464.923] (II) Initializing extension DRI3
[   464.924] (II) Initializing extension X-Resource
[   464.924] (II) Initializing extension XVideo
[   464.924] (II) Initializing extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[   464.924] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[   464.939] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized i965
[   464.939] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
[   464.939] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[   464.939] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DGA
[   464.939] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DRI
[   464.939] (II) Initializing extension DRI2
[   464.943] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1920x1080@60.0 on eDP1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[   464.943] (II) intel(0): Setting screen physical size to 508 x 285
[   464.998] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[   464.998] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   464.998] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[   464.998] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "Keyboard Defaults"
[   464.998] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[   464.998] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[   464.999] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   464.999]    compiled for 1.20.3, module version = 0.28.2
[   464.999]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[   464.999]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[   464.999] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[   464.999] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[   464.999] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[   464.999] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   465.001] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   465.001] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[   465.001] (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
[   465.012] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2/event2"
[   465.012] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[   465.012] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "is,gb"
[   465.012] (**) Option "xkb_options" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[   465.047] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   465.047] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[   465.047] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Asus Wireless Radio Control (/dev/input/event4)
[   465.047] (**) Asus Wireless Radio Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   465.047] (**) Asus Wireless Radio Control: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[   465.047] (**) Asus Wireless Radio Control: Applying InputClass "Keyboard Defaults"
[   465.047] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Asus Wireless Radio Control'
[   465.047] (**) Asus Wireless Radio Control: always reports core events
[   465.047] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[   465.047] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   465.048] (II) event4  - Asus Wireless Radio Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   465.048] (II) event4  - Asus Wireless Radio Control: device is a keyboard
[   465.048] (II) event4  - Asus Wireless Radio Control: device removed
[   465.122] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/ATK4002:00/input/input4/event4"
[   465.122] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Asus Wireless Radio Control" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[   465.122] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "is,gb"
[   465.122] (**) Option "xkb_options" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[   465.124] (II) event4  - Asus Wireless Radio Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   465.124] (II) event4  - Asus Wireless Radio Control: device is a keyboard
[   465.124] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event9)
[   465.124] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   465.124] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[   465.124] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "Keyboard Defaults"
[   465.125] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[   465.125] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[   465.125] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event9"
[   465.125] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   465.126] (II) event9  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   465.126] (II) event9  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[   465.126] (II) event9  - Video Bus: device removed
[   465.145] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input9/event9"
[   465.146] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[   465.146] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "is,gb"
[   465.146] (**) Option "xkb_options" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[   465.149] (II) event9  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   465.149] (II) event9  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[   465.150] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event0)
[   465.150] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   465.150] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   465.151] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event1)
[   465.151] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   465.152] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[   465.152] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "Keyboard Defaults"
[   465.152] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Sleep Button'
[   465.152] (**) Sleep Button: always reports core events
[   465.152] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[   465.152] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   465.154] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   465.154] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
[   465.154] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: device removed
[   465.202] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1/event1"
[   465.202] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[   465.202] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "is,gb"
[   465.202] (**) Option "xkb_options" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[   465.205] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   465.205] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
[   465.208] (II) config/udev: Adding input device USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam: USB2.0 UV (/dev/input/event8)
[   465.208] (**) USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam: USB2.0 UV: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   465.208] (**) USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam: USB2.0 UV: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[   465.208] (**) USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam: USB2.0 UV: Applying InputClass "Keyboard Defaults"
[   465.208] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam: USB2.0 UV'
[   465.209] (**) USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam: USB2.0 UV: always reports core events
[   465.209] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event8"
[   465.209] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   465.212] (II) event8  - USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam: USB2.0 UV: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   465.212] (II) event8  - USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam: USB2.0 UV: device is a keyboard
[   465.212] (II) event8  - USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam: USB2.0 UV: device removed
[   465.276] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/input/input8/event8"
[   465.276] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam: USB2.0 UV" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[   465.276] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "is,gb"
[   465.276] (**) Option "xkb_options" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[   465.280] (II) event8  - USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam: USB2.0 UV: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   465.280] (II) event8  - USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam: USB2.0 UV: device is a keyboard
[   465.282] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Elan Touchpad (/dev/input/event7)
[   465.283] (**) Elan Touchpad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
[   465.283] (**) Elan Touchpad: Applying InputClass "touchpad"
[   465.283] (**) Elan Touchpad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[   465.283] (**) Elan Touchpad: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
[   465.283] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[   465.283] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module synaptics
[   465.283] (EE) Failed to load module "synaptics" (module does not exist, 0)
[   465.283] (EE) No input driver matching `synaptics'
[   465.283] (II) Falling back to input driver `libinput'
[   465.283] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Elan Touchpad'
[   465.283] (**) Elan Touchpad: always reports core events
[   465.283] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
[   465.283] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   465.287] (II) event7  - Elan Touchpad: is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[   465.290] (II) event7  - Elan Touchpad: device is a touchpad
[   465.290] (II) event7  - Elan Touchpad: device removed
[   465.346] (**) Option "Tapping" "on"
[   465.346] (**) Option "TappingButtonMap" "lmr"
[   465.346] (**) Option "NaturalScrolling" "true"
[   465.347] (**) Option "ScrollMethod" "edge"
[   465.347] (**) Option "ClickMethod" "clickfinger"
[   465.347] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.0/i2c_designware.0/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN1000:00/input/input7/event7"
[   465.347] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Elan Touchpad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 11)
[   465.352] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[   465.352] (**) Elan Touchpad: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[   465.352] (**) Elan Touchpad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   465.352] (**) Elan Touchpad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[   465.357] (II) event7  - Elan Touchpad: is tagged by udev as: Touchpad
[   465.363] (II) event7  - Elan Touchpad: device is a touchpad
[   465.365] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Elan Touchpad (/dev/input/mouse0)
[   465.365] (**) Elan Touchpad: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
[   465.366] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Headphone (/dev/input/event10)
[   465.366] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   465.366] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   465.368] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event11)
[   465.368] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   465.368] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   465.369] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event12)
[   465.370] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   465.370] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   465.371] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event13)
[   465.371] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   465.371] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   465.373] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event14)
[   465.373] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   465.373] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   465.374] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 (/dev/input/event15)
[   465.374] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   465.374] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   465.376] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Asus WMI hotkeys (/dev/input/event6)
[   465.376] (**) Asus WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   465.376] (**) Asus WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[   465.376] (**) Asus WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "Keyboard Defaults"
[   465.376] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Asus WMI hotkeys'
[   465.376] (**) Asus WMI hotkeys: always reports core events
[   465.376] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[   465.376] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   465.378] (II) event6  - Asus WMI hotkeys: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   465.378] (II) event6  - Asus WMI hotkeys: device is a keyboard
[   465.378] (II) event6  - Asus WMI hotkeys: device removed
[   465.395] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/input/input6/event6"
[   465.396] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Asus WMI hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[   465.396] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "is,gb"
[   465.396] (**) Option "xkb_options" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[   465.398] (II) event6  - Asus WMI hotkeys: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   465.398] (II) event6  - Asus WMI hotkeys: device is a keyboard
[   465.399] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event3)
[   465.399] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[   465.399] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "system-keyboard"
[   465.399] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "Keyboard Defaults"
[   465.399] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[   465.399] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[   465.399] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[   465.399] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   465.401] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   465.401] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[   465.402] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
[   465.426] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3/event3"
[   465.426] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 13)
[   465.426] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "is,gb"
[   465.426] (**) Option "xkb_options" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
[   465.429] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[   465.429] (II) event3  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[   465.432] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PC Speaker (/dev/input/event5)
[   465.432] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   465.432] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   466.922] (II) intel(0): EDID vendor "AUO", prod id 10029
[   466.922] (II) intel(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[   466.922] (II) intel(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  141.00  1920 1936 1952 2104  1080 1083 1097 1116 -hsync -vsync (67.0 kHz eP)
[   941.003] (EE) Failed to open authorization file "/run/lightdm/root/:0": No such file or directory
```

I don't know if there are any other logs that would shed light on what's wrong so let me know if you want some other log output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was exactly this different file. Apparently if `XkbOptions` are set in another file it seems that the last file to be parsed overwrites anything that was set earlier (no guide I looked up mentioned this so I didn't think twice about it). So I deleted it since it didn't contain anything useful and now all is good.